# Backreference to named capture group in notepad++ not working

Tags: notepad++

According to the [docs](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#capture-groups-and-backreferences), I should be able to access named capture group, but I can't seem to get it to work.

E.g.:

Text to search through:

```
Can you find me?
```

The following regex find fails:

```
(?!)(?<a>find me)|\g{a}
(?!)(?<a>find me)|\g'a'
(?!)(?<a>find me)|\g<a>
(?!)(?<a>find me)|\k{a}
(?!)(?<a>find me)|\k'a'
(?!)(?<a>find me)|\k<a>
```

However, this succeeds:

```
(?!)(?<a>find me)|(?1)
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong? I'm using v7.9.5.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this doesn't work is because the notation that I was using means match what was matched before.  Thus if that regex matched `foo` last time, that means it needs to match `foo` this time.  In the case in the OP, since that never matched anything before, it won't match anything now.

What I wanted was to run that match pattern.  To do that, the notation is `(?&a)`.